# CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was detected

Tags: c#

Помогите решить проблему. Есть PCI плата и библиотека для упраления PCI-Dask.dll.

Есть пневмосистема, которая состоит из 24 пневмопушек. На каждой пневмопушке установлен датчик срабатывания.

Есть форма с 24 кнопками и 24 textboxами. При нажатии одной из 24 кнопок срабатывает соответствующая пневмопушка. А в один из 24 textbox'ов  выводится количество выстрелов от соответствующей пневмопушки. Но возникает следующая ошибка.

> CallbackOnCollectedDelegate was
> detected
>
> Message: A callback was made on a
> garbage collected delegate of type
> 'Pci7442!Pci7442.Card+Multidelegate::Invoke'.
> This may cause application crashes,
> corruption and data loss. When passing
> delegates to unmanaged code, they must
> be kept alive by the managed
> application until it is guaranteed
> that they will never be called.

Причем возникает не сразу, а после примерно 40 нажатий на различные кнопки.
Также было замечено, что при стрельбе с отсутствием воздуха (датчики не срабатывают в этом случае), проблема не возникает.

Возможно, проблема методе `GetDataFromDigitalInput()`.

```
public class Pci7442
{
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DI_ReadLine (ushort cardNumber, ushort port, ushort line, out ushort state);
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DI_ReadPort (ushort cardNumber, ushort port, out uint value);

    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DIO_GetCOSLatchDataInt32(ushort wCardNumber, byte port, out uint cosLData);

    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DIO_INT_EventMessage(ushort cardNumber, short intMode, long windowHandle, long message, MulticastDelegate callbackAddr);

    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DIO_INT1_EventMessage(ushort cardNumber, short int1Mode, uint windowHandle, uint message, MulticastDelegate callbackAddr);
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DIO_INT2_EventMessage(ushort cardNumber, short int2Mode, long windowHandle, long message, MulticastDelegate callbackAddr);
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DIO_LinesConfig(ushort wCardNumber, ushort wPort, ushort wLinesdirmap);
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DIO_LineConfig(ushort wCardNumber, ushort wPort, ushort wLine, ushort wDirection);
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DIO_PortConfig (ushort cardNumber, ushort port, ushort direction);
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DIO_SetDualInterrupt (ushort cardNumber, short int1Mode, short int2Mode, long hEvent);
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DIO_SetCOSInterrupt32(ushort wCardNumber, byte port, uint ctl, out long hEvent, bool bManualReset);
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DO_ReadLine (ushort cardNumber, ushort port, ushort line, out ushort value);
    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DO_ReadPort (ushort cardNumber, ushort port, out uint value);

    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DO_WriteLine (ushort cardNumber, ushort port, ushort line, ushort value);

    [DllImport("PCI-Dask.dll")]
    public static extern short DO_WritePort (ushort cardNumber, ushort port, uint value);

    }
}
```

Есть `UserControl`, который состоит из 24 кнопок, при нажатии одной из кнопок выполняется  `btn_Click`, `_numberOfPort` - определяет порядковый номер пневмопушки. При использовании `linesControl.ShotLineOutput(CardPci7442, line, _numberOfPort);` вместо `Task.Run(() => linesControl.ShotLineOutput(CardPci7442, line, _numberOfPort));` данная проблема не возникает, но зависает форма:

```
public partial class ButtonControl : UserControl
{
        public ButtonControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private const ushort CardPci7442 = 0;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, ushort> _tableOfLine = new Dictionary<string, ushort>();
        private ushort _numberOfPort;
        public void SetNumberOfPort(ushort numberOfPort)
        {
            _numberOfPort = numberOfPort;
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                var linesControl = new LineControl();
                var cklickedButton = (Button)sender;
                var line = _tableOfLine[cklickedButton.Tag.ToString()];

               // linesControl.ShotLineOutput(CardPci7442, line, _numberOfPort);
                Task.Run(() => linesControl.ShotLineOutput(CardPci7442, line, _numberOfPort));

         }
    }

    class LineControl:ILineControl
    {
        public void ShotLineOutput(ushort numberOfCard, ushort numberOfLine, ushort port)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Pci7442.DO_WriteLine(numberOfCard, port, numberOfLine, Pci7442.Low);
                    Thread.Sleep(70);
                    Pci7442.DO_WriteLine(numberOfCard, port, numberOfLine, Pci7442.High);
                    Thread.Sleep(70);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
  }
```

На каждой пневмопушке установлен датчик, который срабатывает при выстреле и возникает вызов `GetDataFromDigitalInput; cosLData` - число, которое определяет, какой из 24 датчиков сработал:

```
class Card : ICard
    {
        public delegate void Multidelegate();
        private const ushort CardPci7442 = 0;

      public void InitCosInterrupt()
        {
            long hEvent;
            Multidelegate callbackAddr = GetDataFromDigitalInput;
        }

        private uint _cosLData;
        private void SetCosLData(uint value)
        {
            _cosLData = value;
        }
        public uint GetCosLData()
        {
            return _cosLData;
        }

        private void GetDataFromDigitalInput()
        {
            uint cosLData;
            Pci7442.DIO_GetCOSLatchDataInt32(CardPci7442, 0, out cosLData);
            SetCosLData(cosLData);
            GC.KeepAlive(this);
        }
    }
```

В основной форме создается 24 кнопки и 24 текстовых поля, каждую мс срабатывает таймер, который преобразует полученное с PCI число `_card.GetCosLData()` в номер пневмопушки.

```
public partial class Pci7442Form : Form
    {
        private readonly ICard _card = new Card();
        private const ushort CardPci7442 = 0;
        public Pci7442Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _card.RegisterCard(CardPci7442);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            _card.InitCosInterrupt();

            btnControl1.CreateButtons();
            btnControl1.SetNumberOfPort(0);

        }

        private void GetCountOfShoots_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                var aRandom = new Random();
                var numberOfSensor = Math.Log(_card.GetCosLData(), 2);
                if (!double.IsNegativeInfinity(numberOfSensor))
                {
                    var t = txBxUserControl1.TextBoxsArray[Convert.ToInt32(numberOfSensor)];
                     //var t = txBxUserControl1[aRandom.Next(0, 24)];
                    t.Value++;
                }
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: При привели много кода, который никому не интересен, но не привели того, что реально вызывает ошибку. Желательно приводить минимальные примеры, вызывающие ошибки. В вашем случае ошибка - в вызове DIO_INT_EventMessage, DIO_INT1_EventMessage или DIO_INT2_EventMessage

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема - в вызовах DIO_INT_EventMessage, DIO_INT1_EventMessage или DIO_INT2_EventMessage. Посмотрите, какой делегат туда передается. Делегат - это тоже объект .NET, и как и все объекты он может быть собран сборщиком мусора. Но сборщик мусора не видит, используется делегат неуправляемым кодом или нет. Поэтому надо хранить ссылку на переданный в неуправляемый код делегат в течении всего времени, когда этот делегат может быть вызван.